# how to resume app in deep link in android?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to add deep-link to my app, the user does some stuff then the browser launches then getting back to the app by clicking on a button, the problem is that I need to resume the activity and not start it again. I tested the deep link by a script in adb shell and it is working fine but not from the browser.

here is how my code looks like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="me"
                android:host="test" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

adb script:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.MAIN -d "me://test" com.example.myapp
```

HTML:

```
<a href="intent://test/#Intent;scheme=me;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;package=com.example.myapp;end">Back To App</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a launchMode to this activity with 'singleInstance'

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MapsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="me"
            android:host="test" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I think "singleTask" is better choice instead of  "singleInstance"